# Python: Open a (line) shapefile and calculate distance to point given as a longitude-latitude tuple

Tags: python, shapefile, line, distance, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe in Python with longitude and latitude values of certain locations (see sample below):

```css
        Index     Long       Lat                       
        0        -98.58       29.49     
        1        -85.73       38.19
        2        -46.65       -23.56
```

I would like to calculate how far these locations are from a hurricane trajectory. I have the trajectory (line) as a shapefile.

Is is possible to do this directly in Python (I know how to do it in other programs, but want to do it in Python directly)?

Answer (score 2):

Python packages have matured a lot since this question was asked. Here is a complete solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd


# The 2021 Hurricane Ida 2021 track line. From here: 
# https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/best_track/al092021_best_track.zip

track_line = gpd.read_file('./AL092021_lin.shp')

#-------------
cities = [{'city':'New York',
           'lat' : 40.6,
           'lon' : -74.0},
          {'city':'Nashville',
           'lat' : 36.1,
           'lon' : -86.7},
          {'city':'New Orleans',
           'lat' : 29.9,
           'lon' : -90.0},]

# List to data.frame
cities_df = pd.DataFrame(cities)

# data.frame to geo data.frame
cities_geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    cities_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(cities_df['lon'], cities_df['lat'], crs='EPSG:4326'))

#-------------
# Convert both line and points to the same projected CRS. This ensures the underlying
# unit of measure is meters, and any distance calculations will be accurate.
# 5072 is Conus Albers projection for the USA, a good choice since the track line
# goes across 20+ lines of longitude and 30+ of latitude. 
# Other regions of the world will need to adjust the CRS.
common_crs = 'EPSG:5072'
track_line = track_line.to_crs(common_crs)
cities_geodf = cities_geodf.to_crs(common_crs)

# The track line shapefile actually contains several lines, each of which describe the hurricane
# strength at the time. To measure the shortest distance from the track to each city,
# do a union of all tracks into a single line.
single_track_line = track_line.unary_union

# Measure and save the distance to each city.
cities_geodf['distance_km'] = cities_geodf.distance(single_track_line) / 1000

cities_geodf
```

Output

```
          city   lat   lon                         geometry  distance_km
0     New York  40.6 -74.0  POINT (1829691.938 2166930.425)    34.917658
1    Nashville  36.1 -86.7   POINT (828435.810 1490504.218)    80.619535
2  New Orleans  29.9 -90.0    POINT (578612.536 776550.486)    56.203402
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Python directly, you will need a helper library unless you want to re-invent the proverbial GIS wheel.

The libraries I would suggest are [fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/) and [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html). Fiona will be enable you to load shapefiles with python, Shapely will enable you to manipulate / analyse them, e.g. `object.distance` in [this section](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-analysis-methods) of the manual from your points to your hurricane.

You will also need to export the dataframe into some format that shapely understands, e.g. the `Point` class, but since these are simple points that should be relatively straightforward.

Note that fiona requires OGR/GDAL and Shapely requires geos, so you may need to find precompiled versions of these if you are using Windows.

Comment: Shapely operates with euclidean on a flat plane, it is not suitable for geographic lat/lon data. https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/examples.html#basic-geodesic-calculations would be a better approach.